# iter all possible tetris block forms

Tags: c++, permutation, tetris, variants

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Programming Contest Question: Counting Polyominos](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650762/programming-contest-question-counting-polyominos)

There are different types of Tetris shapes. For example in shape like letters `T L I Z J O S`.

I'm trying to get an algorithm that can create these blocks.
I'm using C++, but pseudocode would be good enough. Any ideas how to solve it or how to describe the problem to search better for it?

Block is the smallest part of a Tetris shape. If you have 4 blocks to create a shape, then there are only 7 possible shapes:

```
X      X    X
X  XX  X    X   X   XX  XX 
X  XX  XX  XX  XXX XX    XX
X
```

Rotations doesn't count. If you have 3 blocks, then you can shape only 2 blocks:

```
X   X
X  XX
X
```

How many shapes exist when you have `n` blocks? And how do they look like?

Comment: Generally to solve these kinds of problems, you should start with paper and pen; find your algorithm and then write up the code to do it. Don't try to write code for an algorithm you don't know yet - this process tends to end up with writing bad code and having to rewrite everything anyway. Try to solve a few cases (i.e. `n = 3, 4, 5, etc.`) and look for the common pattern. In any event, you could always brute force.

Comment: Answer is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650762/programming-contest-question-counting-polyominos

Comment: @BoBTFish kaoD's answer helped me a lot starting at the top left makes it all simpler as he said, for me too. SO at its best, thanks.

Comment: @AdamStelmaszczyk thanks for fixing my problems with the English language. My text was too much influenced by my mother-language.

Comment: @RageD Well that should have been my first try.