# flatMap or bind in Python 3?

Tags: python, functional-programming

Python provides list comprehensions that provide map/filter type functionality. Can I do a flatMap aka bind operation with this? I've seen solutions with itertools or other add-on libraries. Can I do this with core Python?

```
# this
[[x,10*x] for x in [1,2,3]]
# will result in unflattened [[1, 10], [2, 20], [3, 30]]
```

Comment: `itertools` is included in the stdlib, so it is by definition "core Python."

Comment: @adsmith: No, it's "Python stdlib" by definition. What OP means is as a language feature, like list comprehension syntax for `map` and `filter`

Comment: "or other add-on libraries" suggests that the OP might not realize `itertools` is part of Python.

Comment: Just cuz I don't want to reinvent the wheel other than for purely academic purposes, what's the solution with `itertools`?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077015/python-list-comprehensions-compressing-a-list-of-lists.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
[y for x in [1, 2, 3] for y in [x, 10*x]]
```

Just add another `for` to the list comprehension.

Comment: For clarification -- list comps are written in the same order you'd write `for` loops. First you'd do: `for x in [1,2,3]:` then indent and do `for y in [x,10*x]:`, then `yield y` or whatever you like. It still feels like backwards ordering to me (`for y in [x, 10*x] for x in [1,2,3]` makes more sense to me left-to right) but there ya have it.

Comment: @adsmith: The right-to-left variant gets awkward if you add filtering with `if`

Comment: Oh it makes sense either way, I just have to flip my brain sideways to see the for loops anytime I see "nested" list comprehensions like this.

Comment: that works. That syntax seems illogical. A non-nested for comprehension has the source on the right and the yielded value on the left. This nesting works in the opposite order with no apparent logic to it. It will do for now regardless of elegance.

Answer (score 0):

See [python list comprehensions; compressing a list of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077015/python-list-comprehensions-compressing-a-list-of-lists).

```
from functools import reduce
def flatMap(array: List[List]): List
    return reduce(list.__add__, array)
    # or return reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, array)
```