# Efficiently build a list comprehnsion of numbers and lists

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, processing-efficiency

I have a list of functions. Each function may return either a float or a list of 2 floats. I need to build a flat list of results using a list comprhension. 
For efficiency reasons, I need to build the results using one single iteration. For the same reason, the for loop is not an option (this is my belief... Is this correct?).

Input:

```
funcs=[[function_1, arguments_function_1],[function_2,arguments_function_2]...[function_n, arguments_function_n]
```

where function_j is a previously defined function. arguments_function_j is the list of arguments for funtion_j.

Tentative call:

```
results=[f[0](f[1]) for f in funcs]
```

The above call is syntactically correct but does not return the results in the format I need. In facts, assuming that the forth function returns a list, the final result would be

```
[1,2,3,[4,5],6] instead of  [1,2,3,4,5,6] as I need
```

I tried the following:

```
results=[f[0](f[1]) if type(f[0](f[1]))==float\ 
else f[0](f[1])[0],f[0](f[1])[1]\
for f in funcs]
```

But the `f[0](f[1])[0],f[0](f[1])[1]` part is not syntactically correct. It should be placed between bracktes but then it would not solve the problem.

Any hint?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Comment: please check if the original question answers yours.

Comment: These questions should help:
 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1077015/python-list-comprehensions-compressing-a-list-of-lists 
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21418764/flatmap-or-bind-in-python-3

Comment: Hi, yes I read that post but it does not fix my problem. The suggested solution there, assumes that ALL elements are lists like l=[[1],[2],[3,4],[5]]. My case is different. In my case the input is l=[1,2,[3,4],5]  and the suggested solution rises an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you just need to chain your values so instead of

```
results=[f[0](f[1]) for f in funcs]
```

just do

```
import itertools
result = list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(f[0](f[1]) for f in funcs))
```

(that will flatten your list of results, wrapped in `list` to force iteration)

see also: [Making a flat list out of list of lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/making-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

You can create it with a comprehension using a helper function, but don't forget to time it vs a loop to see if you actually gain performance.

```
import collections
def sequencify(x):
  return x if isinstance(x, collections.Sequence) else (x,)
results = [x for (f, a) in funcs for x in sequencify(f(a))]
```

You can also test whether changing `sequencify` to your specific use case makes it faster, e.g

```
sequencify = lambda x: (x,) if type(f) == float else x
```

But, in truth, if you're looking for performance consider modifying the functions to return a tuple with 1 float instead of just a float and then you don't need the expensive type checks and can use the standard list-flattening technique:

```
results = [x for (f, a) in funcs for x in f(a)]
```

EDIT - my quick tests show that returning tuples of floats is faster than lists of floats by almost 25%:

```
$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; funcs=[ (random.choice([lambda a: [a], lambda a: [a,a]]),random.random()) for i in range(10000) ]' 'result=[x for (f, a) in funcs for x in f(a)]'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.98 msec per loop

$ python3 -m timeit -s 'import random; funcs=[ (random.choice([lambda a: (a,), lambda a: (a,a)]),random.random()) for i in range(10000) ]' 'result=[x for (f, a) in funcs for x in f(a)]'
100 loops, best of 3: 2.27 msec per loop
```

Comment: COOL! In facts, returning ALWAYS a list is the most efficient solution. Thank you!!!!

Comment: using tuples instead of lists, works great and faster. Thank you so much